# Python regex match sequential html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to match only sequential occurrences of a specific tag in a snippet of html. 
For the test string "`blah <em>BAD</em> blah blah blah <em>Time</em> <em>Warner</em> <em>Satan</em>. The blah ..`", I want to only match 'Time', 'Warner' and 'Satan' (either as separate strings or one group, doesn't matter) but not 'BAD'.

My closest attempt so far is `(<em>(?P<match>.*?)</em>[\s\.]){2,}`, which gives me 'Satan'. At least it seems to be enforcing the 2 or more, but not returning everything in that match. I'm guessing a solution involving positive lookaheads is what I need but I can't seem to get anywhere with those.

I've looked at various other related questions but couldn't seem to find a suitable solution. Most related questions are simply filled with answers stating that HTML should never be parsed with regex, instead of answering the question. I'd be happy with an lxml/BeautifulSoup solution, as long as it enforces the sequential property of my requirements but I'm most interested in the regex, even just from a curiosity point of view. I know that what I'm looking for must be possible with regex.

Thanks for your help and input.

Edit: I've realised that I could get around this by using a more simple approach, by matching all instances of the tag with `<em>(?P<match>.*?)</em>`, iterating over each match object and comparing the start and end position of each match. It'd work but I'd rather find a neater solution.

Comment: Obligatory link [to a glorious SO post on HTML and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regular expressions? Really, BeautifulSoup is the superior tool to handle HTML.

Comment: So you want to match sequences of matching tags, with nothing in between them other than whitespace, of at least 2 tags or more?

Comment: I really don't get your requirements. Why should Time, Warner be matched and BAD shouldn't ?

Comment: Yes Martijn, that about sums it up nicely. And thanks Stefano, I've read that before. The context of the problem just means that a simple regex would be a preferred solution. I'm using lxml elsewhere for serious parsing, but these are just highlighted snippets returned by Solr. I'm not sure how Beautiful Soup would give positional info about a tag?

Comment: @HamZa The context is to do with Solr highlighting token matches, but the way it breaks up the fragments means you sometimes get matches that span multiple fragments. I want to ignore singleton tags, or rather deal with them separately after dealing with the multiple matches.

Comment: @IcelandicHoney So something [like **this**](http://regex101.com/r/fE4qL6) ? `(?s)<em\s*>(?:(?!</em\s*>).)*</em\s*>(?=\s*<em\s*>|(?:(?!<em\s*>).)*$)` ?

Comment: @HamZa, don't think that that's what he wants. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/dB3pF3).

Comment: Thanks for trying @HamZa but no, not quite right.

Comment: @IcelandicHoney: BeautifulSoup provides easy access to *sibling* tags and text. It is trivial to find tags and their siblings and see if there is a consecutive run.

Comment: Cheers @MartijnPieters I'll read up on the sibling functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're curious about a re solution, it might look like this:

```
html = "blah <em>BAD</em> blah blah blah <em>Time</em> <em>Warner</em> <em>Satan</em>. The blah .."

rx = r"""(?x)          # extended mode - enable comments
    (                  # match a tag
        <em            # tag name
          [^<>]*       # maybe also attributes
        >              # open tag matched
        (              # now match the tag body
            (?<!</em)  # there must be no closing tag before a character
            .          # a body character
        ) *            # some more characters like this
        </em>          # closing tag
        \s*            # maybe some spaces after it
    ){2,}              # repeat the whole thing twice or more
"""

print re.sub(rx, r'{{\g<0>}}', html)
# blah <em>BAD</em> blah blah blah {{<em>Time</em> <em>Warner</em> <em>Satan</em>}}. The blah ..
```

Comment: Thank you! At first look this seems like the answer I was looking for. I don't think I'll ultimately use this (I'll probably use the approach mentioned in the edit) but it is precisely the solution I wanted to see. Would you mind updating your answer with a breakdown of the regex expression please? I'll test this a bit later when I have time and accept the answer if I can't break it.

Comment: Ok, so I played around with this a bit. I realise now I could've been more clear with requirements, I don't actually need to support attributes. I am in control of the tags, it's not actually some random html input. Anyway, that works fine with re.sub, but it doesn't to work with findall. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @IcelandicHoney: you might want to enclose the whole thing into another pair of `()` so it gets captured by findall. But you'll get the whole block at once `['<em>Time</em> <em>Warner</em> <em>Satan</em>']`. I don't see any way to get `['<em>Time</em>', '<em>Warner</em>', '<em>Satan</em>']` as separate matches.

Comment: Well that would do, just a bit confused about findall's behaviour with groups. Incidentally, my original attempt works (for my needs) when used in re.sub but I had only been testing with findall.